# Glassfish Deployment Failed IllegalStateException

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, glassfish, derby

Trying to deploy to Glassfish, but keep receiving this exception:

```
Error occurred during deployment: Exception while loading the app :  
java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start:  
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError.  
Please see server.log for more details.
```

We are using a Derby database.

Here's the stack from the log:

> Exception while invoking class com.sun.enterprise.web.WebApplication
>   start method java.lang.Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException:
>   ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException:
>   java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError at
>   com.sun.enterprise.web.WebApplication.start(WebApplication.java:138)
>   at org.glassfish.internal.data.EngineRef.start(EngineRef.java:130) at
>   org.glassfish.internal.data.ModuleInfo.start(ModuleInfo.java:269) at
>   org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.start(ApplicationInfo.java:301)
>   at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:461)
>   at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:240)
>   at
>   org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:389)
>   at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$1.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:348)
>   at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:363)
>   at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1085)
>   at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1200(CommandRunnerImpl.java:95)
>   at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1291)
>   at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1259)
>   at
>   org.glassfish.admin.rest.ResourceUtil.runCommand(ResourceUtil.java:214)
>   at
>   org.glassfish.admin.rest.ResourceUtil.runCommand(ResourceUtil.java:207)
>   at
>   org.glassfish.admin.rest.resources.TemplateListOfResource.createResource(TemplateListOfResource.java:148)
>   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601) at
>   com.sun.jersey.spi.container.JavaMethodInvokerFactory$1.invoke(JavaMethodInvokerFactory.java:60)
>   at
>   com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$ResponseOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:205)
>   at
>   com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:75)
>   at
>   com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:288)
>   at
>   com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.SubLocatorRule.accept(SubLocatorRule.java:134)
>   at
>   com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
>   at
>   com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.SubLocatorRule.accept(SubLocatorRule.java:134)
>   at
>   com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
>   at
>   com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:108)
>   at
>   com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
>   at
>   com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84)
>   at
>   com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1469)
>   at
>   com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1400)
>   at
>   com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1349)
>   at
>   com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1339)
>   at
>   com.sun.jersey.server.impl.container.grizzly.GrizzlyContainer._service(GrizzlyContainer.java:182)
>   at
>   com.sun.jersey.server.impl.container.grizzly.GrizzlyContainer.service(GrizzlyContainer.java:147)
>   at
>   org.glassfish.admin.rest.adapter.RestAdapter.service(RestAdapter.java:148)
>   at
>   com.sun.grizzly.tcp.http11.GrizzlyAdapter.service(GrizzlyAdapter.java:179)
>   at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.HK2Dispatcher.dispath(HK2Dispatcher.java:117)
>   at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$Hk2DispatcherCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:354)
>   at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:195)
>   at
>   com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:849)
>   at
>   com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:746)
>   at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1045)
>   at
>   com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:228)
>   at
>   com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
>   at
>   com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
>   at
>   com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
>   at
>   com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
>   at
>   com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
>   at
>   com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
>   at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71) at
>   com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
>   at
>   com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

What might be causing this?

Comment: As I remember, sometimes war file couldn't be refreshed and this exception is thrown.
Remove war folder from glassfish directory. Then redeploy it.

Comment: This may be a class loading problem...are you sure that this is the complete stacktrace? Looks like the cause is missing.